# How to execute multiple spark-submit commands using python script

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to execute multiple spark-submit commands using a python script.

**Ex:**

```
spark-submit --class com.demo.DemoApplication1 --master local[2] Demo1.jar
```

```
spark-submit --class com.demo.DemoApplication3 --master local[2] Demo2.jar
```

```
spark-submit --class com.demo.DemoApplication3 --master local[2] Demo3.jar
```

Comment: You can use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.htmlhttps://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) to submit shell command in python. Shouldn’t a simple shell script do the job for you?

Answer (score 0):

you can use os.system() to run your commands using python like this :

```
import os
os.system('command')
```

so you can probably just use it like this :

```
import os
os.system('spark-submit --class com.demo.DemoApplication1 --master local[2] Demo1.jar')
os.system('spark-submit --class com.demo.DemoApplication1 --master local[2] Demo1.jar')
```